# Geonames database query locally

Tags: mysql, sqlite, geolocation, geonames

If I import the Geonames database to a MySQL or SQLite database, how can query the database by latitude and longitude?
I need to find the current country code based on a given geolocation (latitude and longitude).
In other words, if I have a database with gps coordinates, how can I accurately get the closest one to a given latitude and longitude?

I'm looking for a standalone solution because of rate limits of most reverse geocoding services.

Thank you.

Comment: This depends of the structure of the actual database you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a beautiful article by Seth McLean that describes this situation perfectly and provides a MySQL query that does exactly what I need: to search a geonames database by latitude and longitude.
Maybe this helps someone else: http://clickherelabs.com/2015/01/distance-searching-and-mysql/

Comment: Link is 404. Now at https://clickherelabs.com/blog/distance-searching-and-mysql/  (or archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20210624064153/https://clickherelabs.com/blog/distance-searching-and-mysql/ )